# Did i find a bug in php or .....?

Tags: php

Did i find a bug in php or is something else wrong?
Given a date starting at 2018-03-25 ending on 2018-03-2018 in 2015 is 3, 2016, 2017, 2018 is 2 en 2019 it's 3 again

see the code used

```
$startdate_2015 = strtotime(date('2015-03-25'));
$enddate_2015 = strtotime(date("2015-03-28"));
$nights_2015 = floor($enddate_2015 - $startdate_2015);
echo 'nights in 2015: '.$nights_2015 = floor($nights_2015/(60*60*24));
echo '<p>';
$startdate_2016 = strtotime(date('2016-03-25'));
$enddate_2016 = strtotime(date("2016-03-28"));
$nights_2016 = floor($enddate_2016 - $startdate_2016);
echo 'nights in 2016: '.$nights_2016 = floor($nights_2016/(60*60*24));
echo '<p>';
$startdate_2017 = strtotime(date('2017-03-25'));
$enddate_2017 = strtotime(date("2017-03-28"));
$nights_2017 = floor($enddate_2017 - $startdate_2017);
echo 'nights in 2017: '.$nights_2017 = floor($nights_2017/(60*60*24));
echo '<p>';
$startdate_2018 = strtotime(date('2018-03-25'));
$enddate_2018 = strtotime(date("2018-03-28"));
$nights_2018 = floor($enddate_2018 - $startdate_2018);
echo 'nights in 2018: '.$nights_2018 = floor($nights_2018/(60*60*24));
echo '<p>';
$startdate_2019 = strtotime(date('2019-03-25'));
$enddate_2019 = strtotime(date("2019-03-28"));
$nights_2019 = floor($enddate_2019 - $startdate_2019);
echo 'nights in 2019: '.$nights_2019 = floor($nights_2019/(60*60*24));
echo '<p>';
```

Comment: what version of php are you using? all 3 for me using php 7.1

Comment: all 3 for me even after using version 4.4.9 via sandboxphp

Comment: "ending on 2018-03-2018"?

Comment: FWIW, `date('2015-03-25')` does exactly the same as just `'2015-03-25'`.

Comment: In the UK at least, the last Sunday in March is when the clocks go forward, which will have an impact on this

Comment: Depending on timzone, some of these intervals start on standard time and end on daylight savings time. Doing arbitrary computation with seconds is not the correct way to compute what you want. Use [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php)

Comment: I can only reproduce this on the Berlin timezone (though I may not have been very thorough) it does seem buggy unless there's some odd daylight savings rules in effect. http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/18bc3cc3dda1c925ae6e043db8541887b0b85df5

Answer (score 2):

The difference is simple:

```
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/Berlin');

echo strtotime('2015-03-28') - strtotime('2015-03-25'), PHP_EOL;
echo strtotime('2016-03-28') - strtotime('2016-03-25'), PHP_EOL;
echo strtotime('2017-03-28') - strtotime('2017-03-25'), PHP_EOL;
echo strtotime('2018-03-28') - strtotime('2018-03-25');
```

```
259200
255600
255600
255600
```

In 2015, the [DST](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Daylight_saving_time) switchover fell on March 29th, after your tested time range. In all other years it fell between March 25th and 28th, resulting in an hour less of time difference.

Comment: http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/e961a936e6eb1bd8d3ec604184b8d44fab09e2b8 seems to back this up also the PHP DST database seems to go up to 2037 so anything after that is not accurate

Comment: @apokryfos because of [Y2K38 problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Year_2038_problem).

Answer (score 2):

Depending on the timezone, some of these intervals start on standard time and end on daylight savings time. This is why the difference is not always `3*24*60*60` seconds.

Doing arbitrary computation with seconds is not the correct way to compute differences between dates. Use [`DateTime::diff()`](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php):

```
foreach (range(2015, 2019) as $year) {
    $start = new DateTime($year.'-03-25');
    $end   = new DateTime($year.'-03-28');
    $diff  = $end->diff($start);
    echo("Year: $year, nights: {$diff->days}\n");
}
```

Comment: Honestly don't understand the DST bit but this solution works - so thank you

Comment: When DST starts, one hour (i.e. 3600 seconds) is skipped. When it ends, one hour is duplicated. If the DST starts inside the interval then the difference is not of `3*24*3600` seconds but `3600` seconds less. This combined with `floor()` makes your code report one day less. Your original code works with [`round()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.round.php) but the code is easier to understand if you use [`DateTime`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.datetime.php) and [`DateInterval`](http://php.net/manual/en/class.dateinterval.php).